# Read logs from log4net like in Elmah?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, log4net

Is there any tool for reading logs from log4net files like Elmah?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://logjoint.codeplex.com/ this is a tool in which you can define your own rules to read your log file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/)

> Chainsaw v2 is a companion application to Log4j written by members of
>   the Log4j development community. Like a number of Open Source
>   projects, this new version was built upon inspirations, ideas and
>   creations of others. Chainsaw v2 has it's roots from the original
>   Chainsaw utility written by Oliver Burn, and with inspiration from the
>   Log Factor 5 utility contributed by ThoughtWorks Inc.

It works well with log4net too

Comment: Chainsaw can read regular text log files, try the latest developer snapshot, the setup GUI is much improved and there are a ton of new features: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy